# Postgresql trigger to select and write data into new table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.1

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 on Windows.

I am collecting data automatically from a machine into a PostgreSQL DB and this is working correctly. The data is being saved in several tables and the one I am interested in is called `testrecord`. I have a second static table called `testcode` and a join between the tables. I want to select some of the incoming data in `testrecord` and populate a new table called `finaldata`, where there is a match on `parameter` and the `testid` which is not blank (null).

**Question 1**

Is an `INSERT INTO` and `JOIN` the best way of doing this?

**Question 2**

All the fields at the moment are varchar. When I add a integer field
in the table `finaldata` (such as auto incrementing serial) I get
messages such as `column "FdataID" is of type integer but expression
is of type character varying` or `column "FdataID" is of type integer
but expression is of type record`

The code for my function is below:

```
INSERT INTO finaldata 
    SELECT 
        "testrecord"."Record", 
        "testrecord"."Sample", 
        "testrecord"."SampleOrig",
        "testrecord"."Parameter", 
        "testrecord"."Result", 
        "testrecord"."ResultOrig", 
        "testrecord"."Units", 
        "testrecord"."OperatorID", 
        "testrecord"."ObsTime", 
        "testrecord"."MsgTime", 
        "testcode"."Machine", 
        "testcode"."TestName", 
        "testcode"."ShortTestName", 
        "testcode"."TestID"
    FROM testrecord 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN testcode 
            ON  ("testrecord"."Parameter" = "testcode"."Parameter") 
            AND ("testrecord"."Machine" = "testcode"."Machine")
    WHERE ("testcode"."TestID") IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
INSERT INTO finaldata 
    SELECT "testrecord"."Record", /* some column skipped */ 
        FROM testrecord LEFT OUTER JOIN testcode ON ("testrecord"."Parameter" = "testcode"."Parameter") AND ("testrecord"."Machine" = "testcode"."Machine")
        WHERE ("testcode"."TestID") IS NOT NULL;
```

The first thing is: Into which columns shall `INSERT` write the stuff produced by the `SELECT` part? You have to specify it like this:

```
INSERT INTO finaldata ("Record", ...)
    SELECT "testrecord"."Record", /* some column skipped */ 
    ...
```

Your strange message about wrong types might be caused by this.

The second thing is:

```
... WHERE ("testcode"."TestID") IS NOT NULL;
```

Any you imply that you want to use this code inside a function (the trigger function I guess). Each call to this statement would not just insert one new row into `finaldata`, it would insert *everything*. Duplicate entries are then a certain thing.

So:

- Fix the `INSERT` part
- Fix the missing qualifier in the `SELECT` part.

Oh, yes, question one: As long as a `SELECT` query produces the correct data, it is good enough to be used within an `INSERT` :-) If a `JOIN` helps to produce the correct data -- that's OK.

Comment: Great - you have put me on the right road - I no longer get the strange messages and the data is inserted correctly. You are also right that I am getting duplicates - I`m not sure how to fix this. What I want to happen is for a single record to be created in the new table finaldata when there is a match on the parameter value between the tables. Perhaps I should ask a new question?

Comment: I assume, that your trigger is a row-level trigger attached to the table `testrecord`. In you trigger function you can then access the "magic" rows `NEW` and `OLD` which contain the new and old data of `testrecord`. You can use these to add filters to your `SELECT`. I know nothing about your data, but a wild guess based on the column names would be: `WHERE testcode."TestID" = NEW."TestID"` You can lookup the detail for `OLD` and `NEW` in the PostgreSQL docs in the "Trigger" section.